# "Access Denied" when trying to access file in web app

Tags: java, file, jsp, uri

I have an xslt file stored in the folder ***Project/tools***. (I'm using Netbeans IDE.)

I try to access this file in my code, but at run time, I get an `AccessControlException: access denied`.

The code is:

```
java.net.URI xsltURI = new java.net.URI(myUtil.getUri("xsltFile.xslt"));
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xsltURI)));
```

The `myUtil` instance must be used to access the URI for reasons not important here.  I printed its output, and it correctly gives the relative path of the file.

I have tried to prefix the relative path with `file:///` and `file:///[fulldomain]`, but in each of these cases, it actually tries to access a hard drive on the server, even though I did not give a drive name anywhere. (!) It tries to access ***C:[relative-path]***, which isn't even where the file is anyway.

If I omit `file:///` then I get that `the URI is not absolute`, and if I just give the full web address of the file I get a `NullPointerException`.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:  Following my comment below, my code resembles

```
java.net.URI xsltURI = new java.net.URI("https://host" + myB2U.getUri("xsltFile.xslt"));
        
java.net.URL xsltURL = xsltURI.toURL();
        
java.net.URLConnection myConnection = xsltURL.openConnection();
        
myConnection.connect(); //AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission"...
        
java.io.InputStream xsltStream = myConnection.getInputStream();
       
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltStream));
```

Is there something obvious that is wrong?

Comment: Okay.  From what I've gathered, I'm supposed to instantiate a `URL` object with the path of the file.  From there, I'm supposed to be able to initialize a `URLConnection` from the `URL`.  After I call the `URL`'s `connect()` method, I'm supposed to be able to obtain an `InputStream` by calling the `getInputStream()` method.  However, as I call the `connect()`  method, I get an `AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission ")`.

Comment: Are you using a security manager in your application? If yes, you might need to grant the SocketPermission to your code in the security policy file

Comment: Yeah.  Needed to add a permission.

Answer (score 0):

The file:// protocol tells Java to use file access to open the stream.  If you don't want file access you should use a different protocol such as http://.

If you're using a relative path the URI should look something like file://./My/Relative/Path.  The 3rd slash means that it is relative to the root.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered, I'm supposed to instantiate a `URL` object with the path of the file. From there, I'm supposed to be able to initialize a `URLConnection` from the `URL`. After I call the `URL`'s `connect()` method, I'm supposed to be able to obtain an `InputStream` by calling the `getInputStream()` method.